# How to send "Connection: close" header to the webservise server from Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, http-headers, connection, delphi-xe2, transport

I want to close the connection after finishing my work, but my webservice server has implemented"connection : keep-alive". I have to close the connection for new users, sometimes it need. How can I  send "Connection: close" header to the webservise server from Delphi XE2.

Comment: How are you sending the request to begin with? Which component/framework are you using?

Comment: I use THTTPRIO class instance to send request.

Comment: Unfortunately, `THTTPRIO` does not give you any control over the `Connection` header. `THTTPRIO` uses either Indy or WinInet depending on how it is compiled. Indy's `TIdHTTP` component defaults to HTTP 1.1, which uses keep-alives by default, and THTTPRIO forces keep-alives when using WinInet. So either way, there is no option to change that behavior in `THTTPRIO` without altering its source code.

Comment: Actually, that is not entirely true. `THTTPReqResp` (which you can access via the `THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode` property) has an `OnBeforePost` event. When `THTTPReqResp` uses Indy, the `Data` parameter of that event is a pointer to a `TIdHTTP` object, which you could type-cast to access the `TIdHTTP.Request.Connection` property. But that is only triggered for `POST` requests, but unfortunately not for `GET` requests. But it shouldn't matter, because `THTTPReqResp` disconnects after each `TIdHTTP` request, unless the `THTTPReqResp.IOHandler` property is assigned a user-defined I/O object.

Comment: Is there any way manually adding connection header. For example onBeforeExecute event of THTTPRIO